# Choosing spatial statistics approach (in Arc or QGIS) for two point files?

Tags: qgis, arcmap, distance, spatial-statistics

I have two shapefiles made up of points, in which I am trying to statistically show their spatial relationship.

Here is my data:

[image]

The black points are landslides, and the points ranging from blue to red are points of channel steepness calculated continuously along a river network.

Basically I'm trying to find a way to numerically show that the landslides occur close to sections of the river that are steeper (light blue to red).

I'm struggling to choose which analysis (either in ArcMaps or QGIS) that would allow me to asses the distance between the landslides and the points in the river channel, with the additional variable of channel steepness.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use spatial join (it exists with both ArcGIS and QGIS) to extract the attributes of the closest "slope" point for each landslide point. You can then look at the distribution of "slope" values for all your points.